# why I can't use IntelliSense in snippet? Is there a switch that can be controlled?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I want to know why I can't use IntelliSense in snippet? Is there a switch that can be controlled?

Comment: Did you try manually triggering IntelliSense with `ctrl+space`? In practice, there are many times when VSCode would not show IntelliSense when you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this setting to `false`:

> Editor › Suggest: Snippets Prevent Quick Suggestions
>
> Control whether> an active snippet prevents quick suggestions.

```
"editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": true
```

`true` is the default, sounds like you want `false`.