# code completion not working in snippet VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, code-completion

So when I create a class for example in visual studio code, I can do it all manual and then code completion works just fine see image below:

[image]
So in the image above I have typed all the code so far by hand NOT using any snippets.

But in the image below I created the class using a snipped see image below: 
[image]
But When I fill in the required fields from the snippet code completion is not working. See image below:
[image]

So my question really is how do I get code completion / suggestions to work inside of the fields of a snippet? Or is this not possible in vscode?

If any clarification or extra information is needed let me know so I can add it!

Comment: Have you tried with [TAB] instead of [ENTER]?

Comment: else try [CTRL] + [SPACE]

Comment: The highlighted text is only for typing the name of the class, when done, press [TAB] and the text won't be highlighted anymore you can come back to add inheritance | interfaces

Comment: @IvanGarcíaTopete [TAB] just exits me out of the snippet.. :(

Comment: @clankill3r [CTRL] + [SPACE] yeah that works, but I was hoping for a way for VScode to do it automatically whilst typing.

Comment: @IvanGarcíaTopete yeah that is also possible but a bit of an inconvenience, and i was just hoping to make my life more convenient ;)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52847989/why-i-cant-use-intellisense-in-snippet-is-there-a-switch-that-can-be-controlle/52881972#52881972  Your answer is there.  Because that answer was never accepted, this question cannot be flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: I moved my answer here so that hopefully it can be accepted and then I will mark the other linked question as a duplicate of this so that it can be properly closed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try changing this setting to `false`:

> Editor › Suggest: Snippets Prevent Quick Suggestions
>
> Control whether an active snippet prevents quick suggestions.

```
"editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false
```

`true` is the default, sounds like you want `false`.

Comment: This is a bad default, I literally thought this was a bug and was searching for the issue on github to support! Thanks for this awesome Q&A to both of you.

Comment: something something duplicate answering?